# git - How do I unstage a new file that was created in a new directory?

Tags: git

If I unstage a new file that was added to an already existing directory then it is unstaged correctly.  However if I create a new directory, create and add a new file in that new directory, and then try and unstage it then only the directory is unstaged and the new file disappears completely.

```
$ git status
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

   new file:   src/main/resources/existingdir/newFileInExistingDir.json
   new file:   src/main/resources/newdir/newFileInNewDir.json

$ git rm --cached src/main/resources/existingdir/newFileInExistingDir.json
$ git rm --cached src/main/resources/newdir/newFileInNewDir.json

$ git status
Untracked files:

   src/main/resources/schemas/newdir/
   src/test/resources/existingdir/newFileInExistingDir.json
```

This behaviour is the same whether i use `git rm --uncached` or `git reset HEAD`

How can I unstage new files that were created in new directories?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. you removed both of the files in your script. What do you want to know?

Comment: Thank you @eckes that is indeed the problem.  What obscure behaviour!  Do you want to make a full answer so I can accept it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you're observing is normal for Git: if nothing is tracked inside a certain directory, the whole directory is shown as untracked instead of listing every single file contained in that directory as untracked.

Regarding your question:

> How can I unstage new files that were created in new directories?

You have already done everything neccessary and what you wanted to achieve was actually already done.